# print_r($_SESSION) gives &gt and some data in wierd format?

Tags: php, session

My Code:

```
session_start();
echo '<pre>';print_r($_SESSION);echo '</pre>';
exit(0);
```

**Output:**

```
<pre>Array
(
    [User_ID] =&gt; 124
    [user_info] =&gt; a:7:{s:4:"name";s:10:"Vaibhav EC";s:15:"isAccountLinked";s:1:"0";s:17:"Account_Linked_id";s:1:"0";s:10:"fb_user_id";s:15:"100004895282088";s:29:"facebook_infinite_session_key";s:100:"CAACHc0Q0fJUBAIhMUS4KL8HrsJejl5ZCiZC4qZAZCllIfyxIdws2BzqpRGVgaZAPhReJFVlnN69C9QLDrgJuYmn8R8BdoxaiVZA";s:8:"group_id";s:1:"6";s:10:"member_url";s:10:"vaibhav-ec";}
)
</pre>
```

**My Question**:I want to use `[[user_ID] and [user_info]` data,But how do i format this in a way(like a normal,clean array) that i can use it.

Comment: Was so difficult to google "what is &gt"...?

Comment: &gt is greater than symbol. Use unserialize as noted below by eRIZ.

Comment: @eRIZ:ok..but my main issue is to format the session...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unserialize($_SESSION['user_info'])
```

And then check what do you have.

Comment: ok..grt that cleaned up my data..but how can i use some data that still has &gt attached with it..i mean i cant put that data in my table with that..i need to clean it up too

Comment: This "&gt;" is just an escaping for text representation for data. It's a quite unclear what you want to achieve - print_r shows the variable's structure and if you put it into HTML, the ">" *must* be escaped in order not to mess up the other markup. Specify what do you really want to achieve.

Comment: lets say i want to store [User_ID] in a variable...without that &gt..how would i do that...mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: I shown you what to do. I'm afraid you're asking about PHP basics.

Answer (score -1):

```
$_SESSION['user_ID']
$_SESSION['user_info']
```